# Puppet syncing dir

Tags: directory, centos, puppet

Still does not work
In/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp

```
file { "/home/render/installation/":  
 ensure => "directory",  
 owner  => "render",  
 group  => "render",  
 recurse => "true",  
 mode   => "0750",  
 source => "puppet:///files/installation/",  
 }
```

Dir still is empty on client

```
ls /etc/puppet/files/installation/
1  2  3  4  5
```

On puppet client in log

Mar 21 12:28:12 lw-003 puppet-agent[28098]: (/File[/home/render/installation/]) Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call search on /file_metadata/files/installation with {:checksum_type=>"md5", :recurse=>true, :links=>"manage"}

Mar 21 12:28:12 lw-003 puppet-agent[28098]: (/File[/home/render/installation/]) Could not evaluate: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/files/installation Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///files/installation: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/files/installation
Mar 21 12:28:12 lw-003 puppet-agent[28098]: Finished catalog run in 0.28 seconds

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found this question on Google. I had to change the path to the files for the manifests (modulename/manifests/init.pp):

```
"puppet:///files/installation/",
```

to:

```
"puppet:///modules/files/installation/",
```

The notation without /modules/ was deprecated in 2.7 and no longer supported in newer versions:

```
DEPRECATION NOTICE: Files found in modules without specifying 'modules' in file path will be deprecated in the next major release.  Please fix module 'modulename' when no 0.24.x clients are present
```

Answer (score 0):

---

try this example,

```
  file {
    "/scratch/usern/testmod" :
      ensure => directory,
      source => "puppet:///files/testmod",
      recurse => true,
      owner => "usern",
      group => "groupn",
      mode => "0775",
      backup => false,
  }
```

You have to specify 'files' and if you are doing a recursive copy, specify 'recurse => true'. That might be the solution to your problem.

the 'fileserver.conf' should look something like the following :

```
]# cat /etc/puppet/fileserver.conf
   [files]
     path /etc/puppet/files
     allow *
```

Comment: How does the fileserver.conf looks like in your case ? I have added an example in my answer. Does your look the similar ?